# How to delete disapproved adsense account?

Tags: blogger, adsense, account

Some days ago I created new gmail and  sign up for adsense and that application was disapproved and now disapproved adsense account is not accessible when i signin in adsense.

And now when i signin in adsense with my approved account first it says you have multiple adsense account please choose one and it shows 2 accounts. One is approved and second is disapproved so how can i delete that disapproved account?

Comment: This should be on Super User

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a customer support question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a customer support question

Answer (score 3):

I think deleting your disapproved Gmail account will not solve your problem. You can simply use this link https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/account_cancel and fill out the form with appropriate details and submit your cancellation request to Google AdSense. It may take a few days to process your request.

Comment: The link no longer works.

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple trick for it ,if your account is linked with multiple accounts then simply delete all Gmail accounts and create a new account and resubmit it .i think its hopeful help to you.

Comment: but one of those account is very important to me

Comment: delete gmail accounts!? Isn't it a bit drastic?